# How to Rewrite a python function "get_dummies" using pyspark?

Tags: python, function, pyspark, databricks, one-hot-encoding

How to rewrite this python code using pyspark? The .get_dummies is the in-built python function generally used to map categorical values to some Integer value (One-hot encoding)

```
model_input = pd.get_dummies(model_input, prefix=['DGohe'], columns=['DiagnosisGroup'], drop_first=False)
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://www.skytowner.com/explore/one_hot_encoding_in_pyspark

Comment: get_dummies isn't a built in python function, its a pandas function